# I'm beautiful and dangerous

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I am the goddess of dusk and dawn
And I never stray far.
I'm beautiful and dangerous
And I've never been a star.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you

> Venus

I am the goddess of dusk and dawn

> Called the morning star or evening star

And I never stray far.

> Venus is always found relatively near the horizon

I'm beautiful and dangerous

> Venus the goddess is beautiful and Venus the planet has a very hostile, corrosive and dangerous atmosphere

And I've never been a star.

> Though called the morning star or evening star, it is really a traveler (planet)

Comment: That would have been my answer. +1

Comment: "I never stray far..." from the Sun. This is why it's only seen at dusk or dawn.

Answer (score 0):

Is it...

> <s>the moon?</s> (Chowzen already said it was incorrect)

*I am the goddess of dusk and dawn*

> The moon is most visible at night, but also during the twilight periods (dusk and dawn).

*And I never stray far.*

> It's always visible in the night sky.

*I'm beautiful and dangerous*

> It is beautiful but I'm not sure why it would be considered dangerous.

*And I've never been a star.*

> It's a natural satellite, but not a star (and it has never been one).

Comment: "I am the goddess of dusk and dawn"
The moon is visible in the deep night and the mid-afternoon, at least at times.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to mislead you. That is incorrect *because*  The moon is visible in the deep night and the mid-afternoon, as opposed to "dusk and dawn."

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm not great with these terms to be honest. xD

Comment: TBH, I'm just trying to augment [my billable hours](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/559/year/puzzling/2018-01-01/22519#22519) before January 1st. This question sucks.